# How can I parse R syntax from R?

Tags: regex, r, parsing

I am trying to put together a little script which would track back the history of an object, by analyzing the R history. I am stuck at efficiently parsing R commands and splitting them. Consider the following R command:

```
for( i in 1:10 ) { a[i] <- myfunc() ; print( sprintf( "done step %d; proceeding", i ) )  }
```

Splitting at semicolons or curly brackets is not a problem, but what about the semicolons (or other special things) which are in quotes? I end up going char by char and keeping track of whether I am in a quote of not (and also of the backslashes...). This is footwork, and I'm sure there is something simpler, probably invented around the time Unix was born. A clever regex, maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `parse`. It returns an expression which can be subsetted into the various components of the parse tree:

```
x <- parse(text='for( i in 1:10 ) { a[i] <- myfunc() ; print( sprintf( "done step %d; proceeding", i ) )  }',n=1)


x[[1]]
for (i in 1:10) {
    a[i] <- myfunc()
    print(sprintf("done step %d; proceeding", i))
}

x[[1]][[1]]
`for`

x[[1]][[4]]
{
    a[i] <- myfunc()
    print(sprintf("done step %d; proceeding", i))
}

x[[1]][[4]][[2]]
a[i] <- myfunc()
```

Comment: Great, that was easier than I thought!

Comment: if you want to convert expression to string is `capture.output(print(x[[1]]))` right way to do or is there something easier?

Comment: @geektrader `as.character` works with expressions. `deparse` might also be of interest.

Comment: @James: it only generates a single unparsed value.

Comment: @geektrader: you can use length() on any of the objects and recursively walk through the parsed parts. Additional advantage: the class() on any of the parts of the expression tells you what they are (name, syntax element etc.)

Comment: You might find https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how much details you need, but beside the base `parse` function you might also check out the awesome `parser` package that is really fast to do its job and also returns much more details compared to `parse`. Quick demo:

```
> library(parser)
> parser(text='for( i in 1:10 ) { a[i] <- myfunc() ; print( sprintf( "done step %d; proceeding", i ) )  }')
expression(for (i in 1:10) {
    a[i] <- myfunc()
    print(sprintf("done step %d; proceeding", i))
})
attr(,"data")
   line1 col1 byte1 line2 col2 byte2 token id parent top_level           token.desc terminal                       text
1      1    0     0     1    3     3   270  1     77         0                  FOR     TRUE                        for
2      1    3     3     1    4     4    40  2     77         0                  '('     TRUE                          (
3      1    5     5     1    6     6   263  4     77         0               SYMBOL     TRUE                          i
4      1    7     7     1    9     9   271  6     77         0                   IN     TRUE                         in
5      1   10    10     1   11    11   261  8      9         0            NUM_CONST     TRUE                          1
6      1   10    10     1   11    11    78  9     15         0                 expr    FALSE                           
7      1   11    11     1   12    12    58 10     15         0                  ':'     TRUE                          :
8      1   12    12     1   14    14   261 11     12         0            NUM_CONST     TRUE                         10
9      1   12    12     1   14    14    78 12     15         0                 expr    FALSE                           
10     1   15    15     1   16    16    41 14     77         0                  ')'     TRUE                          )
11     1   10    10     1   14    14    78 15     77         0                 expr    FALSE                           
12     1   17    17     1   18    18   123 18     74         0                  '{'     TRUE                          {
13     1   19    19     1   20    20   263 20     22         0               SYMBOL     TRUE                          a
14     1   20    20     1   21    21    91 21     28         0                  '['     TRUE                          [
15     1   19    19     1   20    20    78 22     28         0                 expr    FALSE                           
16     1   21    21     1   22    22   263 23     25         0               SYMBOL     TRUE                          i
17     1   22    22     1   23    23    93 24     28         0                  ']'     TRUE                          ]
18     1   21    21     1   22    22    78 25     28         0                 expr    FALSE                           
19     1   19    19     1   23    23    78 28     40         0                 expr    FALSE                           
20     1   24    24     1   26    26   265 30     40         0          LEFT_ASSIGN     TRUE                         <-
21     1   27    27     1   33    33   297 32     34         0 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE                     myfunc
22     1   33    33     1   34    34    40 33     37         0                  '('     TRUE                          (
23     1   27    27     1   33    33    78 34     37         0                 expr    FALSE                           
24     1   34    34     1   35    35    41 35     37         0                  ')'     TRUE                          )
25     1   27    27     1   35    35    78 37     40         0                 expr    FALSE                           
26     1   36    36     1   37    37    59 39     74         0                  ';'     TRUE                          ;
27     1   19    19     1   35    35    78 40     74         0                 expr    FALSE                           
28     1   38    38     1   43    43   297 44     46         0 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE                      print
29     1   43    43     1   44    44    40 45     69         0                  '('     TRUE                          (
30     1   38    38     1   43    43    78 46     69         0                 expr    FALSE                           
31     1   45    45     1   52    52   297 48     50         0 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE                    sprintf
32     1   52    52     1   53    53    40 49     64         0                  '('     TRUE                          (
33     1   45    45     1   52    52    78 50     64         0                 expr    FALSE                           
34     1   54    54     1   80    80   260 52     54         0            STR_CONST     TRUE "done step %d; proceeding"
35     1   80    80     1   81    81    44 53     64         0                  ','     TRUE                          ,
36     1   54    54     1   80    80    78 54     64         0                 expr    FALSE                           
37     1   82    82     1   83    83   263 58     61         0               SYMBOL     TRUE                          i
38     1   84    84     1   85    85    41 60     64         0                  ')'     TRUE                          )
39     1   82    82     1   83    83    78 61     64         0                 expr    FALSE                           
40     1   45    45     1   85    85    78 64     69         0                 expr    FALSE                           
41     1   86    86     1   87    87    41 66     69         0                  ')'     TRUE                          )
42     1   38    38     1   87    87    78 69     74         0                 expr    FALSE                           
43     1   89    89     1   90    90   125 71     74         0                  '}'     TRUE                          }
44     1   17    17     1   90    90    78 74     77         0                 expr    FALSE                           
45     1    0     0     1   90    90    78 77      0         0                 expr    FALSE
```

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: please note that the `parser` package is not supported by R 3.0.0 because this feature has been implemented by the core R: `?getParseText`